# Exact type information about multidimensional arrays in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, typeinfo

Exact type information can be found in Postgres

I noticed that the type information is a bit inaccurate regarding miltidimensional arrays:

```
create table test (xid int[][] primary key);

insert into test values (array [[2, 4, 2, 7], [1, 5, 6, 0]])

select pg_typeof(xid) from test -- returns integer[]
```

How do I get back the exact type `integer[][]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard bevahior according to the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) :

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
> dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
> considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
> dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
> CREATE TABLE is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time
> behavior.